# Deleting user profiles using Delprof2 and Windows Task Manager

Tags: user-profile, task-manager

I'm having problems with using Windows Task Manager and Delprof2 utility to delete user profiles.

I setup a task in Windows Task Manager to execute Delprof2.exe with /q parameter at each system start (reboot) to delete all profiles.

This setup works sometimes but not all the times and I cannot figure it out the reason for this inconsistency. I have tried on Windows 7 and 10 and the result is same.

Did anyone encounter this problem? Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[How to Automatically Delete User Profiles Older Than a Certain Number of Days Using Group Policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28647.how-to-automatically-delete-user-profiles-older-than-a-certain-number-of-days-using-group-policy.aspx)